# How can I update the style of a button in cs file?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

Im trying to update a style of a button, in cs file (c#), that I created in xaml code.

I searched for a lot solutions but none worked.

```
<flv:FlowListView FlowColumnCount="3" SeparatorVisibility="None" HasUnevenRows="true"
                    FlowItemTappedCommand="{Binding ItemTappedCommand}" FlowLastTappedItem="{Binding LastTappedItem}"
                    FlowItemsSource="{Binding MyCategories}" >

                    <flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button Text="{Binding Name}"
                                TextColor="White"
                                x:Name="CategoryButtons"
                                Clicked="ButtonSelected"
                                ContentLayout="Top"
                                BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                BorderColor="White"
                                BorderWidth="2"
                                CornerRadius="6"
                                Margin="5,5,5,10" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>

                </flv:FlowListView>
```

```
 public void ButtonSelected(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

I have this
[image: regular icon]
I want this
[image: highlighted icon]
Ignore the difference between the two icons

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set the style programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3199424/how-to-set-the-style-programmatically)

Comment: @LarryTang I saw that solution but it's so confusing, may have a better and not that confused solution, and thats what im searching for. And I want update not create in my c# file.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want the style declared/used in your `Xaml`?

Comment: @TaylorD I want my style declared in my Xaml file because the FlowListView code, but i can delcare some style in a ResourceDictionary if it is better. I just want to be able to change my button style through cs file(c#). (Sry for the delay)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, you create style for Button, then you want to change some Button property when Button click, I suggest you can change Button property directly, like this:

**XAML**

```
 <StackLayout>
    <Label
        HorizontalOptions="Center"
        Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!"
        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />

    <flv:FlowListView
        FlowColumnCount="3"
        FlowItemsSource="{Binding categories}"
        HasUnevenRows="True"
        SeparatorVisibility="None">
        <flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button
                    x:Name="CategoryButtons"
                    Margin="5,5,5,10"
                    Clicked="CategoryButtons_Clicked"
                    Style="{DynamicResource buttonstyle}"
                    Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
    </flv:FlowListView>

    <Button
        x:Name="btn1"
        BackgroundColor="Transparent"
        BorderColor="White"
        BorderWidth="2"
        Clicked="btn1_Clicked"
        HeightRequest="40"
        Text="this is test!"
        WidthRequest="300" />
</StackLayout>

  <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style x:Key="buttonstyle" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Transparent" />
            <Setter Property="BorderWidth" Value="2" />
            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="6" />
            <Setter Property="ContentLayout" Value="Top" />
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="BorderColor" Value="White" />

        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

**CS**

```
private void CategoryButtons_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button)sender;       
    btn.BorderColor = Color.Orange;
   }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this solution worked, I did a little bit different, didnt create the ResourceDictionary and the other button, I just kept with my Xaml code and did the c# code that you sent me. But now, if you could help me, when I click again in the button can i reset the style? Like, I click one time in the button the style changes, but when I click again I want to reset the styles.