# How to add a Style to UserControl Resources in C# programmatically?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-style

I'm trying to do this XAML:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Label">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

in C# code.

Here's my attempt in the `UserControl` Constructor:

```
InitializeComponent();

string labelForegroundColor = "Blue";

string labelXAMLStyle = @"<Style xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation' xmlns:x='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml' TargetType=""Label"">
        <Setter Property=""Foreground"" Value=""{LabelForegroundColor}""/>
    </Style>";

labelXAMLStyle = labelXAMLStyle.Replace("{LabelForegroundColor}", labelForegroundColor);

StringReader mainLabelStyleXAMLStringReader = new StringReader(labelXAMLStyle);
XmlReader mainLabelStyleXAMLXMLReader = XmlReader.Create(mainLabelStyleXAMLStringReader);
Style mainLabelStyle = (Style)XamlReader.Load(mainLabelStyleXAMLXMLReader);

this.Resources.Add("LabelStyle", mainLabelStyle);
```

When I have the XAML in my `UserControl` it obviously works, but when I remove the XAML and add the code in my `UserControl` Constructor; it doesn't.

Where am I going wrong?
Do I have to add some sort of Resource Dictionary?

How can I get it right to set the style of all `Label`'s in my one specific `UserControl`?

Comment: Did your tried this one already? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3199424/how-to-set-the-style-programmatically

Comment: I can create the style in C# programmatically, but I don't know how to then set that style as the default style for all Labels in my UserControl. @RonaldHaan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to create a style programatically and then add it to the resources.

```
    Style style = new Style(typeof(Label));
    style.Setters.Add(new Setter(Label.ForegroundProperty, Brushes.Blue));
    Resources[typeof(Label)] = gridStyle;
```

Comment: "Resources[typeof(Label)] = style;" was exactly what I needed :D. Thank you @Dmitri Caragheaur