# Telerik UI for WPF - How to set the ClearButtonStyle of a RadMaskedTextInput in code-behind?

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

I'm using the Telerik UI for WPF framework. This includes the `RadMaskedTextInput` control and I struggle to set the `ClearButtonStyle`. How can I assign a style to it in code-behind?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set the style programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3199424/how-to-set-the-style-programmatically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign a name to your `RadMaskedTextInput` control in XAML.

```
<telerik:RadMaskedTextInput x:Name="MaskedTextInput"/>
```

If your style is defined with a in XAML, use `FindResouce`

```
<Style x:Key="MaskedTextInputStyle" TargetType="{x:Type telerik:RadButton}">
    <!-- Your style definitions -->
</Style>
```

```
var clearButtonStyle = (Style) FindResource("YourResourceKey");
```

You can also create the style in code-behind. Add e.g. setters and triggers to the corresponding collections.

```
var clearButtonStyle = new Style(typeof(RadButton));
```

Then in code-behind - the `*.xaml.cs` file - assign the style.

```
MaskedTextInput.ClearButtonStyle = clearButtonStyle;
```

Comment: Thx can i somehow change shape of this on cross ?

Comment: Of course, add a `Setter` that sets the `Content` property to simply plain text `X` or use a `RadGlyph`. You can read more on that [here](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/styling-and-appearance/glyphs/common-styles-appearance-glyphs-radglyph).